# Adding custom / recorded sounds for power-up

Tags: powered-up

The Powered Up application offers many more sounds than the BOOST app, but the later allows for recording of extra sounds...

How could someone add / record custom sounds for powered-up App?

Comment: I believe it's not possible.. Lego might not have thought of it during development. What's the point if the powered up brick doesn't make sounds anyway? You'll have to teach your phone ventriloquism for that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuFkeCP-Eg) has a solution for Android users.

In the Files app, navigate to:
Internal Storage -> Android -> data -> com.lego.common.poweredup -> files -> PredefinedActivities
Copy the folder containing the project files to:
Internal Storage -> Android -> data -> com.lego.common.poweredup -> files -> Activities

Download and open QuickEdit and navigate to the copied folder.
Open `powered-up-metadata.json` and set these values and save the file:

```
"IsControllerEditingAllowed": true,
"IsCanvasChangeAllowed": true,
"IsPanningAllowed": true,
"Contexts": [
  "freeplay"
],
```

This will unlock the advanced features of Powered Up.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The widget is there, the recorder does indeed open, but nothing gets recorded. The wave is "flat", the mic maybe isn't initializated.

Comment: i think its going to be an issue in lastest version